# An install4j app on centOS without GUI is installed on /usr/local

Tags: centos7, install4j

On CentOS7 without GUI, when trying to install an install4J app, it uses the install folder "/usr/local" and I see in logs that sys.installationDir equals "/usr/local"

On other distro (debian), it seems equals to "/opt"

However if I use a CentOS with a GUI, it chooses the "/opt" folder

Do you know why?

Thanks in advance
Cheers

Edit: I'm using install4j 7.0.10

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If it exists, the installer prefers `/opt` to `/user/local` for the standard installation directory.

Comment: /opt exists on CentOS but is empty.

Comment: You can always set the custom base directory on the installer options step of the media wizard to `/user/local` if you do not like `/opt` as the installation directory